# Trying to style logo and login area on opposite sides of a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am fairly new to bootstrap and am trying to style my homepage so that, on the same row below the menu bar, my logo appears on the left side of the page and my login area appears on the right side of the page. This is my rough idea.

```xml
<section class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <section class="branding">           
            <a href="index.php"><img src="/projectx/images/logo1.png" alt="Logo For Project X"></a>             
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        THIS IS THE LOGIN AREA
    </div>
</section><!-- branding -->
```

This places "THIS IS THE LOGIN AREA" beneath the logo. If I do the following:

```xml
<section class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        <section class="branding">           
            <a href="index.php"><img src="/projectx/images/logo1.png" alt="Logo For Project X"></a>             
        THIS IS THE LOGIN AREA          
        </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">

        </div>
</section><!-- branding -->
```

Then "THIS IS THE LOGIN AREA" gets placed to the right of the logo, but it is right next to the logo.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, if anyone knows of good learning resources I would be grateful. I have come across many but they generally revolve around building a test site which is a far cry from teaching the technology.

UPDATE:

I tried something like the following:

```xml
<section class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <section class="branding">           
            <a href="index.php">
            <img src="/projectx/images/logo1.png"alt="Logo For Project X"> 
            </a>                
        <span style="color:red; float:right;">THIS IS THE LOGIN AREA</span>
        </section>
    </div>
</section><!-- branding -->
```

and ended up with roughly the desired effect, except that "THIS IS THE LOGIN AREA" ends up partially overlapped by the nav-bar.

UPDATE UPDATE:
I tried the following with success. However, not sure this is best-practice. Any tips?

```xml
<section class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        <section class="branding">           
            <a href="index.php"><img src="/projectx/images/logo1.png" alt="Logo For Project X"></a>             
            <span style="color:red; float:right; margin-top:4%; margin-right: 4%; border: 3px black solid; padding: 3%">THIS IS THE LOGIN AREA</span>
        </section>
        </div>

</section><!-- branding -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<section class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="index.php">
            <img src="/projectx/images/logo1.png" alt="Logo For Project X">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <span class="pull-right" style="color:red; border: 3px black solid; padding: 3px;">
            THIS IS THE LOGIN AREA
        </span>
    </div>
</section>
```

Fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8vfs109v/)